# Скрипт в Unity для передвижения мышкой. Когда мышкой нажимаю на персонажа, то он начинает переворачиваться и взлетать, а должен стоять. Что делать?

Tags: unity3d

Написал данный скрипт из гайда, так как сам новичок в этом деле. При нажатии мышкой на персонажа он начинает взлетать в воздух и переворачиваться, а должен либо совсем чуть-чуть подвинуться, либо просто не реагировать на нажатие. Помогите решить данную проблему, вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tank1 : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 targetPosition;
    Vector3 lookAtTarget;
    Quaternion playerRot;
    float rotSpeed = 5;
    float speed = 10;
    bool moving = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            SetTargetPosition();
        }
        if(moving)
            Move();
    }

    void SetTargetPosition()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
        {
            targetPosition = hit.point;
            //this.transform.LookAt(targetPosition);
            lookAtTarget = new Vector3(targetPosition.x - transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y,
                targetPosition.z - transform.position.z);
            playerRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookAtTarget);
            moving = true;
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
                                                playerRot,
                                                rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                                targetPosition,
                                                speed * Time.deltaTime);
    
        if (transform.position == targetPosition)
            moving = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: TargetPosition у вас это то место, куда прилетел луч. После нажатия кнопки луч выпускается и куда-то прилетает. В эту точку и летит ваш игрок. Значит, если луч выпустить куда-то вверх, игрок полетит вверх...

Comment: А вот как мне это исправить? Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на объект он оставался на месте?

Comment: Ты можешь прибавлять позицию, а не переприсваивать

Comment: Я просто не особо шарю вообще в юнити и c#. Что и куда мне нужно написать?